# Navigation from page1.xaml to page2.xaml in windows phone 8

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have two pages: *page1.xaml* and *page2.xaml*. I have created one button on page1.xaml; on its click event I navigate to *page2.xaml*. When I run the application, it fails and the debugger drops me in *App.xaml.cs*. Below is my code:

```cs
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)                
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {  
        // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger                      
        Debugger.Break();             
    }         
}
```

My page1.xaml.cs code behind is:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage     
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()   
    { 
        InitializeComponent();  
        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar                        
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    private void btnDownloded_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)         
    {             
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DownloadedBooksPortrait.xaml", UriKind.Relative));    
    } 
}
```

Comment: first check the type of exception by put you pointer on sender of.. private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)                
   {
      if (Debugger.IsAttached)
      {  
          // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger                      
          Debugger.Break();             
      }         
   }  
when you get this error ..comment below about the error ..and make sure your xaml code is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SourcePage.xaml**

bookName.Id fetching Id and of book and through bookid we will get the id on our destination page and will show the data.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?selectedItem=" +bookName.Id, UriKind.Relative));
```

**DestinationPage.xaml**

On destination page we we will fetch the query parameter as below.

```
   private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        string dir = "Hello" + selectedItem;
   }
```